# Limit of sequence of improper integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have no idea. How to solve that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty } \int_0^{\infty} \! x^{\frac{n}{n+1}} \cdot e^{-x^2} \, dx. $$

Comment: What is the limit of $\dfrac n{n+1}$ as $n\to\infty$ ? As for the integral, let $t=x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $f_n(x) = x^{n/(n+1)}e^{-x^2}$ is bounded above by $g(x) = (1+x)e^{-x^2}$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) dx$ exists as a real number. Hence, by dominated convergence theorem, we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} f_n(x)dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)dx = \int_0^{\infty} xe^{-x^2}dx = -\left.\dfrac{e^{-x^2}}2 \right \vert_0^{\infty} = \dfrac12$$

Comment: I think, i am  not allowed to use  teh dominated convergence theorem because we havent learned it yet. 
Is there another option

Comment: @TED There is generally speaking not really an easier way to prove that we can interchange limit and integral. For some particular cases you may find your way out by explicitly calculating the sequence of integrals. In case you can not, the dominated/monotone convergence theorem is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

$f_n(x) = x^{\frac{n}{n+1}}\cdot e^{-x^2} \leq (x + 1)\cdot e^{-x^2}$ on $[0,\infty)$,

and $g(x) = (x + 1)\cdot e^{-x^2}$ is integrable on $[0, \infty)$ as well. So: $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} x^{\frac{n}{n+1}}\cdot e^{-x^2} = x\cdot e^{-x^2}$. So apply the dominated convergence theorem: $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^\infty x^{\frac{n}{n+1}}\cdot e^{-x^2} dx = \int_{0}^\infty x\cdot e^{-x^2} dx = \dfrac{1}{2}$

Comment: I think, i am  not allowed to use  the dominated convergence theorem because we havent learned it yet. 
Is there another option

Answer (score 0):

In $\newcommand\eps\epsilon\let\geq\geqslant\let\leq\leqslant$case you want to avoid the Dominated Convergence Theorem, we can directly prove that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty(x^{\frac n{n+1}}-x)e^{-x^2}=0.$$
Let $\eps>0$.
The idea is to show that $|x^{\frac n{n+1}}-x|e^{-x^2/2}<\eps$ for all $x>0$ and for sufficiently large $n$. The desired limit will follow from
$$\left|\int_0^\infty(x^{\frac n{n+1}}-x)e^{-x^2}\right|\leq\eps\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/2}=\eps',$$
since $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2/2}<\infty$.
Because $\lim_{x\to\infty}2xe^{-x^2/2}=0$ we can find $x_0>1$ (independent from $n$) such that
$$|x^{\frac n{n+1}}-x|e^{-x^2/2}\leq(|x^{\frac n{n+1}}|+|x|)e^{-x^2/2}\leq2xe^{-x^2/2}<\eps$$
for all $x\geq x_0$ and $n\in\mathbb N$.
For $x<x_0$ we can use $e^{-x^2/2}\leq e^0=1$. It remains to show that we can find $N$ such that for all $n>N$ and all $x<x_0$, $|x^{\frac n{n+1}}-x|<\eps$. We split this into a few cases.

- $x\leq\eps^2$:
  $$|x^{\frac n{n+1}}-x|=x^{\frac n{n+1}}(1-x^{1/n})\leq\eps^{\frac{2n}{n+1}}\cdot1\leq\eps\qquad\text{for all }n.$$
- $\eps^2\leq x\leq1$:
  $$|x^{\frac n{n+1}}-x|=x^{\frac n{n+1}}(1-x^{1/n})\leq1\cdot(1-\eps^{2/n})\leq\eps\qquad\text{for }n\text{ large enough},$$
  since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\eps^{2/n}=1$.
- $1\leq x\leq x_0$:
  $$|x^{\frac n{n+1}}-x|=x-x^{\frac n{n+1}}\leq x_0-x_0^{\frac n{n+1}}\leq\eps\qquad\text{for }n\text{ large enough}$$
  because $x-x^{\frac n{n+1}}$ is monotonically increasing for $x\geq1$ with derivative $1-\frac n{n+1}x^{-1/(n+1)}\geq0$ and because $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_0^{\frac n{n+1}}=x_0$.

Thus in either case we have the desired bound for $n$ large enough.

I believe this method can be generalized to prove the continuity of $\Gamma(t)=\int_0^\infty x^{2t-1}e^{-x^2}dx$ for $t>0$, without using the DCT.